# Android Studio WebView Basic Setup

Tags: android

I've just been following the guide below:
https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#AddingWebView

I created the webview app in the layout and added the internet permission successfully.

The 'load a web page' and 'enable javascript part' won't work. Perhaps I haven't named something correctly or the programming is in the wrong place?

Screenshot- https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdcvH.jpg

Comment: Did you `import android.webkit.WebView;`?

Comment: Can you post the XML as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify that you have the right imports,

```
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I probably should have mentioned i'm a newbie. Where abouts can I check the imports?

Comment: Below the `package line`, Click on the 3 dots or "+" icon near `import`.

Comment: If your problem is the WebChromeClient, you should perform         `myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());`

Comment: Yes it was missing. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try performing `setJavascriptEnabled()` before you perform `loadUrl()`. Also, you are retrieving a reference to the WebView twice using `findViewById`. You should only do it once.

Try this:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
```

Comment: Thank you! :) I couldn't figure out why 'webview' wasnt working in (R.id.webview). The ID name

Comment: The ID name wasn't set for the WebView in the design view*